# KMP Compose Multiplatform DataStore Alternative

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I've been working in my KMP Project (Android-Desktop), but it seems KMP has no supports for Desktop (yet?).

The problem I faced is on this code on androidMain in [sample github repo](https://github.com/android/kotlin-multiplatform-samples/blob/main/DiceRoller/shared/src/androidMain/kotlin/com/google/samples/apps/diceroller/createDataStore.android.kt):

```
fun getDataStore(context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> = getDataStore(
    producePath = { context.filesDir.resolve(dataStoreFileName).absolutePath }
)
```

How can I replace the the directory or path for Desktop?

And if possible, I want to know other DataStore / SharedPreference-like libraries and their use example for KMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found how to do DataStore/SharedPref thing in KMP.

Currently, I'm using [Multiplatform Settings](https://github.com/russhwolf/multiplatform-settings)

Here's the example:

Shared:

```
expect class MultiplatformLocalUserWrapper {
    expect fun createLocalUserPref(): ObservableSettings
}
```

Android:

```
object ContextUtils {

    private var kmpAppContext: Context? = null

    val context
        get() = kmpAppContext
            ?: error("Android context has not been set. Please call setContext in your Application's onCreate.")

    fun setContext(context: Context) {
        kmpAppContext = context
    }
}

actual class MultiplatformLocalUserWrapper {

    val context = ContextUtils.context

    actual fun createLocalUserPref(): ObservableSettings {
        val sharedPref =
            context.getSharedPreferences("user_local", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return SharedPreferencesSettings(sharedPref)
    }
}
```

Desktop (Use JVM):

```
actual class MultiplatformLocalUserWrapper {
    actual fun createLocalUserPref(): ObservableSettings {
        val preferences = Preferences.userRoot()
        return PreferencesSettings(preferences)
    }
}
```

If you wanna go for specific platform for ObservableSettings [see this link](https://github.com/russhwolf/multiplatform-settings/blob/7d3a450cd9da21513e69d9b20e0f14f32fa3120e/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L37)